# How to control box edge for 3D graphics like Plot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

For example

[image]

But I want to strip those box edge except the bottom ones like this

[image]

Note that there is still one redundant edge left, because erasing it will be quite ugly with my image editing tool. Also I need the "y" axis labeled like 2D plot case.

I search the documentation, did't find a way to detailed control the box edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (playing with `AxesEdge`)?:

```
Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Axes -> {True, True, False}, 
Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 12, Bold], Style["y", 12, Bold], None}, 
ViewPoint -> {0, -2, 2}, AxesEdge -> {Automatic, {-1, -1}, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Exactly what I want. I didn't find `AxesEdge` before.+1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Plot3D[-x^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1.94, -1.94, 1.94}]
```

[image]

May be it will do for you.

If not, you may remove all automatic axis and the box and draw the axis by hand as follows, for example:

```
 Show[{
  Plot3D[-x^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1}, {-1, 0.2}}, Axes -> None, 
   Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {-1.94, -1.94, 1.94}],
  Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1.1, -1, -1}}], 
    Arrow[{{-1.1, 1, -1}, {-1.1, -1.2, -1}}]}]
  }]
```

[image]

Then you will, however, need to also draw the ticks and figures in addition, which I did not do here. It cab be done by the same statement `Graphics3D`.

Have fun!

Comment: Hi, @Alexei Boulbitch. Thank you so much for answering. It seems that José Antonio Díaz Navas's answer is a more proper one : )